# Partition not accessible - Access denied in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, permissions

I restored my laptop and when I try to open one of the many partitions (all others work) with my administrator account 'MyAdmin' I get the error: Access denied.

So I started CMD run as Administrator and I can browse this partition. But why doesn't it work with my administrator account MyAdmin ?

And how can I grant Access to all the Admins ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Take Ownership of an Object using TAKEOWN Command**

This command will take ownership of the folder or drive, and all files and subfolders in the folder or drive.

Open an elevated command prompt (administrator).

To grant ownership to administrators group:

```
takeown /F "full path of folder or drive" /A /R /D Y
```

Examples:

```
takeown /F "F:" /A /R /D Y
takeown /F "F:\Folder" /A /R /D Y
```

**To Take Ownership of a Folder or Drive and All Contents using ICALCS Command**

Open an elevated command prompt (administrator).

To set administrators group as owner:

```
icacls "full path of folder or drive" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C
```

Example:

```
icacls "C:\Windows\Folder" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C
```

Comment: ok it looks good - list of: success file xy now owned by the administrators group. But do you have any idea why did it happen  ? Is it because the restoring process was issued by the Administrator role or something ? Thank you

Comment: I've no idea why it happened. You may want to modify your question to see if anyone else has any ideas why.

Comment: I'm an owner now.. but the same error is coming. It looks some program has to be blocking the access..

Comment: anyways.. the system is freshly restored.. so ..